# Problem with force-downloading files with PHP

Tags: php, http-headers

I have problem with force browser to download a file. I found that kind of solution my problem:

```
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name_of_file");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
readfile($name_of_file);
exit;
```

But after that I have my file on screen. Even that make this same result:

```
header('content-type: text/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="$filename"');
echo "TEST";
exit;
```

Where could be a problem?

Comment: @sennin An example URL demonstrating the problem for everyone would be very good. Can you provide one? Also, what browser are you using? Is the problem reproducible on different systems and with different browsers?

Comment: you will get literal `$filename` instead of the actual filename string in your 2nd example btw because you are enclosing with single quotes which doesn't embed the `$filename` string value.

Comment: Problem exist because I have file content on screen instead in file to download. It is happen on every browser. I cannot force any browser to show download file window.

Comment: I know about quotes it's only quick made sample. This is not a quotes problem.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, *attachment* for the [*Content-Disposition* header field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183) is not supported that good. That’s why the [*Content-Type* header field value is more important](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-19.5.1):

> If [the Content-Disposition] header is used in a response with the application/octet-stream content-type, the implied suggestion is that the user agent should not display the response, but directly enter a `save response as...' dialog.

Although an [unknown content type like *application/force-download*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.5.3) is supposed to be interpreted like [*application/octet-stream*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.5.1):

> It is expected that many other subtypes of "application" will be defined in the future.  MIME implementations must at a minimum treat any unrecognized subtypes as being equivalent to "application/octet-stream".

But you should better play it safe and use *application/octet-stream* explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name_of_file));
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . $name_of_file);
readfile($name_of_file);
die();
```

1) It is your responsibility to make sure that file does exist and is readable

2) It may be worth adding `ob_end_clean();` before sending headers (in case you have sent something already)

**EDIT:** Removed useless `;` as per comments from porneL, thnx

Comment: HTTP is a binary-only protocol, `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` is a made-up thing. `Content-Length` is not supposed to have `;`, and it's not quite correct to put `;` after `application/octet-stream`. Filename may need escaping (which, sadly, is very complicated to do correctly and interoperably).

Comment: @porneL: You are absolutely correct about `;`. I have 3 fully working projects where I'm sending generated files (pdf, xls, csv) and 2 of them have no `;` in those places. But one has and somehow it works ... But I will amend my answer to reflect this. Cannot really comment on `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` header though -- I'm just using it as it was present in a solutions when I was investigating this moment years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment');
```

and combine that with `mod_rewrite` or such to put correct filename *in the URL*.

If you have Apache, but you're not using `mod_rewrite`, that works too;

```
http://example.com/download_script.php/nice_filename.xml
```

This causes `download_script.php` to be called. Browsers will "see" `nice_filename.xml` as the filename and you won't need the very messy and unreliable `filename=…` attribute.